# building asp.net 4 project with asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I have created a web application project in asp.net 4.0 and I am trying to build it by setting Target framework 3.5. how can I set the target framework to 3.5 and build this project in visual studio 2010

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project settings, go to Compile, scroll down and click advanced compile options (you can see it in this picture, don't follow the pictures red lines though, they don't apply)
[image]

Once opening the dialog, you can set the target framework here:[image]

Comment: I cant find first screen. How can I get this ? I got second screen though and changed framework but now getting build errors of types and namespaces missing.

Comment: The steps are different here because DalexL is using an MVC application, whereas you are using Web Application Project. Just go directly to the second step :)

Comment: @Irish Thanks for the help with explaining that ;)  @DotnetSparrow Fixing the references will probably be a little bit tricky.  Go ahead and remove the namespaces that it has marked as "missing" because those are most likely new references used in the 4.0 framework (from my experience).  Remember to mark a question as "Answered" if you have found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on Project Properties in Solution Explorer window. Select Application tab and choose which build version you want from the Target Framework drop down.